# swiftui Fatal error: attempting to create attribute with no subgraph

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, ios-simulator, swiftui-navigationlink

Hi whenever i run my ios app in the simulator i get the error `Fatal error: attempting to create attribute with no subgraph: CachedView<KFImageRenderer, ImageBinder> (lldb)` . however, the app seems to run fine in the preview. Does anyone know a fix for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had forgot to add the .environmentObejct(..) to the previews section. Also got it fixed by adding the environment to my preview.